# How does one create a symbolic function execution DAGs that is not evaluated immediately in Python?

Tags: python, design-patterns, graph, tensorflow, sympy

I wanted to create a "symbolic" representation of function calls (in my mind right now the best way to represent this is with a Graph or a DAG or a Tree) i.e. set up an execution graph and then execute the graph later, with the possibility with slightly different inputs or the graph having a completely different state when executed (similarly how TensorFlow does it, with feeds and inputs to the graph).

So for example if I had:

```
graph = f( g('a','b', h('c','d') ), seed )
```

I would have the graph:

[image]

and the essentially have control of how I execute the graph:

```
graph.execute()
```

I feel this is some sort of design pattern since say TensorFlow, Mathematica and SymPy seem to all use (note it seems language independent). Though, I had a hard time finding the name of the design pattern so that I could implement it myself in Python with my own execution graph nodes and data types. Does anyone know how to do this or have a nice link to the name of the design pattern so that I can build this?

Its important for me that the graph creation is as simple as easy as TensorFlow, SymPy etc. In other words. I'd like that I can have multiple syntaxes to create the same graph. For example It shouldn't be to hard to do:

```
h = h('c','d')
g = g('a','b', h )
graph = f( g, seed )
```

if the user wanted to.

Comment: Are you looking for a Python workflow management/piplining library?  If yes, checkout snakemake or ruffus

Comment: I didn't mention Pip, see: http://www.ruffus.org.uk/ and https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @Chris_Rands sorry because you said workflow and then the work piplinining ( I read it as pip---ignore the rest of the word). I will delete my previous comment, my apologies that was silly of me (no wonders it made no sense to me). I will look at those libraries when I get time today. thnx

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "the graph having a completely different state when executed"

Comment: Also take a look at [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick example:

```
# dataflow constructs
#####################

class DelayedFunctionCall:
    def __init__(self, func, *args):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args

    def execute(self):
        args = [arg.execute() if isinstance(arg, type(self)) else arg for arg in self.args]
        return self.func(*args)

def dataflow(func):
    return lambda *args: DelayedFunctionCall(func, *args)
```

Specifically I create `dataflow` as a wrapper around a python function to store the function and arguments into a `DelayedFunctionCall`.

This mechanism is just *storing* the function and arguments, but no execution occurs yet.

Calling `execute()` from a `DelayedFunctionCall` actually resolves the function and arguments stored. Note that `DelayedFunctionCall` takes care to resolve any `DelayedFunctionCall` arguments it received first (by calling `arg.execute()`).

```
# user code
###########

@dataflow
def f(g, seed):
    return g**2 % seed

@dataflow
def g(a, b, h):
    return a * b + h

@dataflow
def h(c, d):
    return c / d

seed = 5

# setting up the execution / dataflow
graph = f(g(1, 2, h(3, 4)), seed)

# no mathematical operations have happened yet; i.e. bodies of f,g,h functions have not been executed yet

# executing the dataflow
print(graph.execute())
```

Note the use of the `@dataflow` decorator. If you want you could also define the functions regularly and later convert them into `DelayedFunctionCall`s:

```
def f(g, seed):
    return g**2 % seed

# do stuff with regular, non-dataflow f

f = dataflow(f) # now f is a DelayedFunctionCall
```

---

You can check out the code (with support for `**kwargs` and the ability to delay binding variables to values until execution time!) on [github.com/pcattori/dataflow](https://github.com/pcattori/dataflow)

Comment: does this still work even if the computation structure is a (potentially complicated) DAG or Tree?

Comment: @CharlieParker: Yes. I've added an example to construct the exact graph you describe in the question. In general this can represent any DAG since you can view the function calls as nodes and the dependencies between function calls as directed edges.

Comment: out of curiosity, is there a way to conserve the really nice syntax `f(g(1, 2, h(3, 4)), seed)` without the need of decorators?

Comment: Yes the decorator syntax is not necessary. You can call `dataflow` directly as I show in the last code block.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understood what you want, It is the syntaxic sugar for defining the graph.

The resulting code is very similar to the one of Pedro Cattori

The major difference is that you don't have to define the `Input` before the graph is defined.

The others little things I changed are:

Rename dataflow in Function

Keep the name of the decorated function via `wraps()` call

Use `hasattr()` instead of Instance testing to allow other class such as `Input()`.

```
import functools

class Input():            
    def set(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def execute(self):
        return self.value

def Function(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def g(*args,**kwargs):
        return Executor(f,args)
    return g

class Executor():
    def __init__(self,f,args):
        self.f = f
        self.args = args
    def execute(self):
        return self.f(*(arg.execute() if hasattr(arg,"execute") else arg
                        for arg in self.args))

@Function
def f(g, seed):
    return g**2 % seed

@Function
def g(a, b, h):
    return a * b + h

@Function
def h(c, d):
    return c / d

seed = Input()

# setting up the execution / dataflow
graph = f(g(1, 2, h(3, 4)), seed)

#you can also do in several steps
H = h(3,4)
graph2 = f(g(1,2,H),seed)

#inputs value can be late binded
seed.set(5)

# executing the dataflow
print(graph.execute()) #2.5625

#both way to the definition give same result
print(graph2.execute()) #2.5625
```

Comment: maybe I didn't explain my question well (and my example is silly, it doesn't actually show the use case I want, I will update in a bit, sorry now that I read the answers up to now I understand what I truly wanted better myself) but the intention is that some arguments to the functions are actually symbolic variables, say 'a','b' are variables that might change with each execution of the graph while 'c','d' are actually fixed strings. The idea is that when one does graph(seed), 'a','b' randomly change while 'c','d' remain fixed. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Do you mean that a and b can be replaced at the execution by for example 2 and 3 ?

Comment: Yes, depending on the seed. More generally the user should be able to do `graph(a=3,b=3).execute()` and it all happens. Now that I think about it I can't think of anything else except pass through the function execution once, collecting pointers to variables that are meant to be able to change and once we call the execute function change them accordingly.

Comment: @XavierCombelle I also thought late variable binding would be a nice addition. If you want to see my implementation for it you can check the github link at the bottom of my answer. Cool to see both of us had the same idea in mind!

Comment: @PedroCattori , your implementation is really short and would worth to be add in your answer